# WPF ListBox apply general Style to ListBoxItems

Tags: wpf, listbox

Is it possible that I can say in the listbox declaration that all items are having that style?
Currently I have to tell that every single item.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ItemTemplate:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="SomeControlStyle" TargetType="SomeControl" >
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ADataTemplate">
        <SomeControl Style="{StaticResource SomeControlStyle}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <SomeControl Style="{StaticResource SomeControlStyle}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Or:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ADataTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: So if i am right this should work?

<ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource Office2010SilverListBoxItemStyle}" Content="{Binding }"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

But it works only "half". The Problem is that i can click the items and the style is working but the get not selected. I use a office style and so the are only on mouseover yellow on click and select nothing happens

Comment: How do you know the item does not get selected? Please add the information in your comment to your question that will make the question better and easier to answer.

Comment: If it is not selected i don t know exactly but my style does not mark it display it as selected. If i am doing something like:
<ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource Office2010SilverListBoxItemStyle}">1. Frame</ListBoxItem>

it works

Comment: If the SelectedItem property of the ListBox is set after clicking an item it is only the visual clue that is missing. You should test that.